# Using jep.invoke() method

Tags: java, python

I need to call a function from a python script and pass in parameters into it. I have a test python script which I can call and run from java using Jepp - this then adds the person.

Eg Test.py

```
import Finding
from Finding import *

f = Finding()
f.addFinding("John", "Doe", 27)
```

Within my Finding class I have `addFinding(firstname, lastName, age)`

However, I wish to be able to do this from within java. Should I be using the `jep.invoke()` method. Does anyone have a hello world example of such a thing being done or forward me to some good examples?

Does anyone have any suggestions please?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This issue seems to have been addressed here:  http://forums.devshed.com/java-help-9/call-python-from-java-591942.html

Answer (score 0):

Easier way to run python code in java is to use [jython](http://www.jython.org/).

**EDIT:** Found an [article with examples](http://wiki.python.org/jython/JythonMonthly/Articles/September2006/1) in the jython website.